# disabled strongly typed checkbox not posted

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

i am trying to post the value of a disabled checkbox in a asp.net mvc 2 application?
the 'test' value on post is false but should be true?

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        model.flag = true;

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
        var test = model.flag;

        return View();
    }

 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<jqscriptfileseperate.Models.MyModel>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2>
 Index</h2>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
   {%>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.flag) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%--   <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.flag) %>--%>
        <%:Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.flag, new {disabled="disabled" })%>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<button type="submit">
    Save</button>
<% } %>
</asp:Content>


  public class MyModel
{
    public bool flag { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

disabled inputs are excluded from form submits, as per the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12).  changing it to `readonly` should give the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the neatest way to deal with this is to put in a dummy disabled checkbox and a hidden field bound to the model:

```
@Html.CheckBox("dummy", new {disabled = "disabled", Checked="true"})
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsCollection)
```

This way the checkbox is greyed *and* and the value still gets posted back.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this one works better

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return false" />
```